# How to call the value of variables from one class to another in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, oop, geolocation

This is my code. I want to call the value of `lat`, `log` variable from `JSONTask` to `onMapReady`.

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line ="";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);

            // JSONObject finalObject = parentObject.getJSONObject();

            String latitude = parentObject.getString("geo");
            String[] coordinate = latitude.split(",");

            double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinate[0]);

            double log = Double.parseDouble(coordinate[1]);

            return lat + " - " + log ;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if(reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tvData.setText(result);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(lat,log);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use shared preferences for such kind of tasks,
that's some kind of hack btw.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `AsyncTask` could be not finished yet when you `onMapReady()` method is called.
You should check this, for example if `(lat != 0 && lon !=)`.

Then, what's the problem is?
Announce variable `lat, lon` in your class.
And, in `onPostExecute()` parse your `String` with `split(" - ")` - it will give you `String array` of two items, then make `lat = Double.parseDouble(yourArray[0])` and `lon = Double.parseDouble(yourArray[1])` to get lat and lon.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define lat and long variables as global.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a listener interface as code below

It is better to wait for map to get ready before you fetch your lat and long. so on `onMapReady` you can execute your AsyncTask and once you get result you can call `addLatLng` to add the marker

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, LatLng> {

    interface OnLatLngReceivedListener {
        void onLatLngReceived(LatLng latLng);
    }

    private OnLatLngReceivedListener listener;

    public JsonTask(OnLatLngReceivedListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected LatLng doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
            String latitude = parentObject.getString("geo");
            String[] coordinate = latitude.split(",");

            double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinate[0]);
            double log = Double.parseDouble(coordinate[1]);
            return new LatLng(lat, log);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(LatLng latLng) {
        if (latLng != null && listener != null) {
            listener.onLatLngReceived(latLng);
        } else {
            // SOME FAILING REPORT MECHANISM
        }
    }
}
```

In your activity/fragment

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    new JsonTask(new JsonTask.OnLatLngReceivedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLatLngReceived(LatLng latLng) {
            addLatLng(latLng);
        }
    }).execute("YOUR_JSON_URL");
}

private void addLatLng(LatLng latLng) {
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
}
```

Note: you might have to write some logic to avoid adding same marker multiple time.